# how access connectionstring in a web.config in other project from a WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, connection-string

I'm having some difficulty to access the connectionstrings in web.config from a WCF "web services"

cenario:
a solution inside visual studio 2010 with 2 web projects, placement and wcfPlacement. 
the web.config that has the connectionstings are inside the placement project.

[image]

The wcfPlacement does not have a web.config as you can see in the picture, but when I build it, it generates one.

from the placement project I can access the connection strings using 
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["XX"].ConnectionString; - ok.

but if I'm inside the service, it gives me an error when I try to access, forcing me to have a connection string declared inside each class that I want database access, and that's not good.

How can I access the connectionstrings that are in th web.config inside the placement project from the wcf ?

I tried:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["webV"].ConnectionString);
```

but it gives me an error:
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at wcfPlacement.Prospect.doLogin(String login, String senha)

tried this inside a class:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig =
            System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/placement");
            System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString;
            if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0)
            {
                connString =
                    rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"];
                if (connString != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("Northwind connection string = \"{0}\"",
                        connString.ConnectionString);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("No Northwind connection string");
            }
```

but I get this error.
    Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Configuration' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: I added the connection strings to the app.config inside the WCF and it worked. when publishing the connectionstrings was copied to the generated web.config, still testing but looks like it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add reference to System.Configuration namespace.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: thanks vaxlt, I forgot to put in the question but i did that, what I didn't know was that I could put the connectionstring in the app.config